# Django ManyToManyField association error - 'ManyToManyDescriptor' object has no attribute 'add'

Tags: django

I'm a beginner and I'm trying to understand why when I receive the results of my API, that I add to my `aliments` field (linked by the ManyToManyField to the `ListAliments` model), are not directly linked to my post.

The API works and the response too:

```
data {
    concepts {
      name: "salad"
      ...
    }
    ...
```

I use as agreed create and add if the result of the API is not already created in the `ListAliments` model. If one of the results is already created I just want to add it (link it to the post). The problem is that it doesn't work.

My first step was to start with: `self.aliments.create(name=concept.name)`

```
class ListAliments(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(editable=False)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=1)     
    
    def save(self, *args,**kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = unique_slugify(self, slugify(self.name))
        super(ListAliments, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=190)
    url_image = models.URLField(max_length=200, default=None)
    aliments = models.ManyToManyField('ListAliments',blank=True, related_name='listaliments_post')
    
    ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.slug:
        self.slug = unique_slugify(self, slugify(self.title))
    ...
    if self.url_image:
        request = ...
        response = ...
        
        if response:
            names = []
            for concept in response.outputs[0].data.concepts:
                current_aliments = ListAliments.objects.filter(name=concept.name)
                if current_aliments.count()<1:
                    create_aliments = self.aliments.create(name=concept.name)
                    self.aliments.add(create_aliments)
                else:
                    existed_aliments = ListAliments.objects.get(name=concept.name)
                    self.aliments.add(existed_aliments)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I try to add with this:

```
current_aliments = ListAliments.objects.filter(name=concept.name)
                    if current_aliments.count()<1:
                        create_aliments = self.aliments.create(name=concept.name)
                        Post.aliments.add(create_aliments)
                    else:
                        existed_aliments = ListAliments.objects.get(name=concept.name)
                        Post.aliments.add(existed_aliments)
```

Comment: Before calling .add within the save method, save it first by calling super().save(*args, **kwargs). It will assign the primary key to post. Many to many relationships needs primary keys to be present on both models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to add the `aliment` to the class `Post` and not to an instance of the class.

You first need to create a `Post` object using `Post.create(...)` or retrieve an existing object using  `Post.objects.filter(...)`

Once you have an instance of a post, you can associate it with the `aliment` using `add()`

#### Edit

`Post` and `ListAliments` are your model names. You need to create an instance of these objects in order to have a relationship. For instance:

```
my_ali = ListAliments.create(name="ali_name")
my_post = Post.create(title="my_post")
```

Now `my_post` can have `aliments`, and `my_ali` can have `posts`. I can add an aliment to the post using

```
my_post.aliments.add(my_ali)
```

Now going back to your code, you are creating an instance of `ListAliment` called `current_aliments`. So far so good.

Next, you attempt to create a relationship using:

```
Post.aliments.add(create_aliments)
```

This doesn't work. `Post` refers to the model definition, not to an instance of a post. You need to first create or retrieve a post.

```
my_post = Post.create(title="new post")
```

Now you have an instance, `my_post`, and can assign `aliments` to that instance.

```
my_post.aliments.add(current_aliments)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer @Hutch. Could you please explain a bit more because I can not see how can create an new entry in ListAliments with your first code :)